# Doing an update to a database with partial data in Go

Tags: go, aws-lambda

So I have the following function in an API:

```
type Product struct {
    Id          int32             `json:"id" db:"id"`
    CompanyId   int32             `json:"companyID" db:"company_id"`
    Name        *string           `json:"name" db:"name"`
    Description *string           `json:"description" db:"description"`
    ExternalId  *string           `json:"externalID" db:"external_id"`
    Tags        types.StringArray `json:"tags" db:"tags"`
    Enabled     bool              `json:"enabled" db:"enabled"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time         `json:"createdAt"`
    UpdatedAt   time.Time         `json:"updatedAt"`
}

func updateProduct(event UpdateProductEvent) (Response, error) {
// TODO - determine how we want to log. fmt jsut does prints. The log package?
fmt.Println("This is updateProduct")

var id int64

err := db.QueryRow(`
    UPDATE 
        v2.products 
    SET 
        company_id = $2, 
        name = $3, 
        description = $4, 
        external_id = $5, 
        enabled = $6
    WHERE id = $1 RETURNING id`,
    Product.Id,
    Product.CompanyId,
    Product.Name,
    Product.Description,
    Product.ExternalId,
    Product.Enabled,
).Scan(&id)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error updating product: " + err.Error())
    fmt.Println("Product: ")
    return Response{}, errors.New("Error inserting product")
}

return Response{
    Id: 8,
}, nil
}
```

So a Product gets passed in and then I need to update the entity in the database. The above works fine in the case where I get a full product passed in. But for this API that might not be the case, it could only be a partial one.

So I might only have two fields in the JSON passed to the API.

So what I'm thinking is passing in an interface{}, instead of the Product so I dont get zero values for fields not set. Then looping through interface{} to get the fields. From those fields I would check if that field exists on the Product object. If it does get the tag from the field, this would be the appropriate column in the database, and then create the query string for the QueryRow call and add all the fields to an interface{} array and let that be the second param. Something like:

```
func updateProduct(event interface{}) (Response, error) {
var values []interface{}
// Loop through the event and get the field and value
for field, i := range event.fields {
    if Product.Has(field.name) {
        //add db tag of Product field to query 
        values = append(values, field.value)
    }
}

err := db.QueryRow(`
    UPDATE 
        v2.products 
    SET 
        //fields from the loop above as needed
    WHERE id = $1 RETURNING id`,
    values...,
).Scan(&id)

...
}
```

I think i can get this, or something like it, to work but it seems like a very round about way to do something very common. I just cant think of any other way to do it.So is there a more common/simpler approach that I'm missing. I cant find anything Googling either.

EDIT: In my haste and attempt to simplfy I left out an important part. This is for an AWS Lambda. So the object passed into updateProduct depends on what comes from the API Gateway. So if i make it the UpdateProductEvent it will parse the json into the object, in this case the Product. If I just make it an interface{} it will basically just make a map.

So if my request is

```
{
    "product": {
        "name": "Test17",
        "externalID": "test17",
        "description": "",
        "companyID": 309
    }
}
```

The first method, setting an explicit object, it will create a Product and fields not in the json will have the 0 value for their field.

If i make it an interface it will be an object with those properties and not the zero values for the rest of the fields in Product

Comment: First of all you need to populate `values` even when the field is empty otherwise your stuff will be in the wrong order. Second I don't understand how using this avoids the problem of unpopulated data. I don't know why an interface will not give the same problem with empty data.

Comment: I made an update to the post. I left out an important piece of information. Basically this is for AWS Lambda. So the request object that comes in can be unmarshalled into an object or if its an interface{} it will jsut make a generic object with the fields from the request and not the zero value fields from Product not in the request. Also the second query would be created dynamically, not hardcoded like i had originally

Comment: did you try upserting the data? if you have a unique key which would be received in every request eg `company_id` or `external_id` use `INSERT` with `ON CONFLICT (company_id) DO UPDATE SET name=COALESCE(EXCLUDED.name, products.name) ....` this will keep the data already available in previous update and will set the new incoming data

Comment: But how does this help? I will still need to do all the above to figure out which fields I want in the query, no? I mean it's definitely something I should look at but I'm going to run into the exact same problem with zero value fields. I will have to use an interface{} and loop through the fields there instead of using a specific struct

Comment: the DB you are using is mysql or postgres?

Comment: it's a Postgres database